# Return multiple vectors from function and add to data frame

Tags: r

An example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)

latLong <- data.frame(long= c(78.0422, -0.1246, 131.035904, 122.3493), 
                     lat = c(27.1750, 51.5007, -25.344646, 47.6205), 
                     name = c("Taj Mahal", "Big Ben", "Uluru", "Space Needle"))
```

Address details from lat/longs are found by a reverse geocode lookup.
The function returns a data frame.

```
results <- revgeocode(c(78.0422, 27.1750), output = "more")
```

We want to return an arbitrarily large set of results
by applying the function to the vectors containing 
the latitude and longitude, writing the results
back to the data frame.

If we want to bring back a single value, we can use mapply.

```
getLocality <- function(long, lat) {
  locality <- revgeocode(c(long, lat), output = "more")
  locality <- locality$locality
  return(locality)
}

localities <- mapply(getLocality, latLong$long, latLong$lat)
```

We can use the function to return the values to the data frame
as a new column.

```
latLong$locality <- mapply(getLocality, latLong$long, latLong$lat)
```

We can also use dplyr.

```
latLong <- latLong %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dplyrLocality = getLocality(long, lat))
```

The output so far:

```
|long    |lat      |name        |locality      |dplyrLocality |
|--------|---------|------------|--------------|--------------|
|78.0422 |27.17500 |Taj Mahal   |Agra          |Agra          |
|-0.1246 |51.50070 |Big Ben     |London        |London        |
|131.0359|-25.34465|Uluru       |Petermann     |Petermann     |
|122.3493|47.62050 |Space Needle|Hulunbeier Shi|Hulunbeier Shi|
```

What about if we want to write back **all** of the result set?

```
getAddress <- function(long, lat) {
  address <- revgeocode(c(long, lat), output = "more")
  return(address)
}
```

What is the cleanest / most efficient / easiest to understand way to write the whole data frame back to the
latLong data frame as multiple new columns? Can you give a few alternative ways of doing it, maybe one using the apply family, and one using dplyr?

Comment: Do you want to create a `data.frame` containing all of the information returned by `getAddress(78.0422,  27.17500)` through `getAddress(122.3493,  47.62050)` and the problem is that the first returns 10 elements while the last only returns six elements?

Comment: If you imagine the desired result as a table in SQL named `historical_sites`, and each tuple is made of a unique key (a composite of long and lat), it would contain the name, address, street, locality, area, country, and so on, of that historic site. So each row would represent a single site, and each column would be a geographic attribute. Does that give you an idea about how the result should look? I tried a few different ways, including `by(latLong, 1:nrow(latLong), function(x) { })` and `dplyr` and `mapply`, none of which quite did what I wanted them to do, or worked for single vals only.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it easily with `purrr` package. `map2_df()` takes two arguments and returns a `data.frame`:

```
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(latLong,map2_df(latLong$long,latLong$lat,getAddress))

str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ long                       : num  78.042 -0.125 131.036 122.349
 $ lat                        : num  27.2 51.5 -25.3 47.6
 $ name                       : Factor w/ 4 levels "Big Ben","Space Needle",..: 3 1 4 2
 $ address                    : chr  "Dashehara Ghat Rd, Dharmapuri, Forest Colony, Tajganj, Agra, Uttar Pradesh 282006, India" "Palace of Westminster, Westminster, London SW1A 2PW, UK" "Uluru Rd, Petermann NT 0872, Australia" "Unnamed Road, Zhalantun Shi, Hulunbeier Shi, Neimenggu Zizhiqu, China"
 $ route                      : chr  "Dashehara Ghat Road" NA "Uluru Road" "Unnamed Road"
 $ neighborhood               : chr  "Dharmapuri" "Westminster" NA NA
 $ political                  : chr  "Tajganj" NA NA "Zhalantun Shi"
 $ locality                   : chr  "Agra" "London" "Petermann" "Hulunbeier Shi"
 $ administrative_area_level_2: chr  "Agra" "Greater London" "Macdonnell Shire" NA
 $ administrative_area_level_1: chr  "Uttar Pradesh" "England" "Northern Territory" "Neimenggu Zizhiqu"
 $ country                    : chr  "India" "United Kingdom" "Australia" "China"
 $ postal_code                : chr  "282006" "SW1A 2PW" "0872" NA
 $ establishment              : Factor w/ 1 level "Palace of Westminster": NA 1 NA NA
 $ postal_town                : Factor w/ 1 level "London": NA 1 NA NA
```

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. I think I messed up the lat/long of the Space Needle ;) Thanks, I'll look at the documentation! Upvoted.

Comment: It's great. You can also use pipes operators as in `dplyr`. Something like `latLong %>% map2_df(.$long, .$lat, getAddress)`